# How to create a Twitter Event Listener

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

today i tried out  Twitter4J and noticed, there was a way to create a event. But i dont know how, because everytime i start it, its stopping itsself after less than 0.2 seconds. Can someone tell me how to Create a EventListener? (And how to reply to a message)

(I am using this code in a "*Listener.java*" file which is opened in "*Main.java*" with "*Listener.listen();*")

```
        public static void listen() {
    UserStreamListener ust = new UserStreamListener() { 
               "(Implementation)"
 };}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UserStreams have not been available on Twitter since 2018. You probably want to try doing the same thing but with a `StatusListener` instead.